# What is too opinionated about this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently stumbled accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22394056/425313).

Which has been closed as primarily opinion based.

> Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

But contrary to the close reason, I see multiple references to facts and authoritative references in the answers.  I'm a bit uncomfortable seeing a well-intentioned question closed without personally being able to justify where it erred.

What line does this question cross to earn the "primarily opinion based" close reason?  Should it be reopened?

Comment: I see authoritative references to the fact that Google uses it and some information on Internet Explorer path limits, but I do not see any authoritative references saying specifically that the path limit was *why* Google chose it.

Comment: I do not see any "authoritative references" in any of the answers, but is that required?  Not if you know the subject matter and can therefore determine whether the answer is useful.  I'm not familiar with the subject matter enough to know if the answer is correct, so I wouldn't vote to close -- or to reopen.  (But it does look likely that the question is asking for an explanation rather than an opinion.)

Comment: A question is closed to stop answers from being added.  If you got an "authoritative answer" then you got what you came for, little reason to be disappointed.  What we don't need is a bunch of answers that try to explain why the letter q is special.  Lots of users will have a guess at it.

Comment: but how do you know that the so-called "authoritative" answer is indeed authoritative, complete, or even correct? could it possibly be that someone else knows more than the SO mods? shiver.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are probably two primary reasons why this would have been voted opinion-based (not related to whether or not it actually *is* opinion-based):

1. At first glance, it *appears* opinion-based, especially because of the title question, "Why do a lot of websites use 'q' for their search function?" Looking at that in isolation, that can easily be considered opinion-based; it appears to ask a coding style question, and it appears to ask reasons for others' style choices that we have no way of knowing.
2. Looking at the answers it attracted, while it is undeniably true that "q" is the first letter of "query", there isn't exactly an ISO standard that specifies that "q" must be used for search query parameters. For all we know, Google chose it because it is the first letter of "quit using Bing".

That said, there is a second question in the question text itself, "is there some technical or browser compatibility reason for this?" No matter how good or silly you think that question is, the answer is categorically "no" and *that* is certainly not opinion-based.

I think the major issue is the title. The question in the title is can be read in a significantly different way from the question in the text itself. If this question's title were edited to ask the more concrete question in the text, it might not be judged so quickly.

There is probably a lesson to be learned about choosing good titles, and phrasing, here, by the way.

Comment: +1. Title will almost always give the first impression of the question, even if the question body doesn't say so (which after all, is a bad idea)

Comment: Quick note, point 2 isn't true, Google themselves [documented](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/xml_reference#request_parameters) [multiple](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2006/07/meaning-of-parameters-in-google-query.html) [times](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012266?hl=en) what q means.

Comment: In short, "ask[s] reasons for other's style choices".  I agree with that line, you cannot give an authoritative answer for another's style choice.  Also agree that this is unfortunately worded copy, I've done my best to polish that title.

Comment: @BradKoch Those documents describe what the parameter's value means. They do not describe the rationale behind the name choice (we would reasonably assume that they chose 'q' because the English word for query starts with 'q' but nothing in these links verifies that, e.g. it could have easily been 's' and the docs still make sense). More importantly, it isn't really relevant. This question isn't about Google, and the "for all we know" sentence isn't the point of #2.

Comment: @JasonC So you're saying a standard is technical justification, but citing historical rationale is unsatisfactory?  The history of q leads through Google, and they left us documentation saying q = search query; including a statement that implies we can't possibly understand their decision is what feels disingenuous.

Comment: @BradKoch The Google docs you linked don't have a rationale for the name. As a proof-by-contradiction of sorts, pretend "s" is the name of their parameter. Now drop "s" in place of "q" in that documentation. Does this introduce any inconsistencies? If the docs said "q was chosen because it is the first letter of query" then it would. But there is nothing like that there. Historical rationale is OK, but in this case there is *no* rationale. Also, incidentally as far as history goes, [aliweb](http://www.aliweb.com/) was est. 5 years prior to Google and used "query".

Comment: I'm going to accept this because I agree with nearly everything you've said in the answer, but I still believe you're severely discounting and waving off the value of the existing content.

Answer (score 2):

I hate the word "opinionated" as if there's some kind of stigma to thinking for yourself instead of resorting to "facts" which are often standardized opinions. It is anti-intellectual at its core. Your question is a very good one and deserves consideration.

I have had questions closed because they were too "opinionated." The problem is that answers are sometimes opinions as there are more than one answer. In my case, I asked what are the best practices for setting up Bootstrap to handle frequent Framework updates. What resulted from that question is a standardization now in Bootstrap 3. Posters all posted their answers and explained how their solution solves the problems and even some critiques of posted solutions. The moderators shutdown the question because it solicited too many opinions with little regard for how the question genuinely benefitted the developer community.

There are lots of gray areas in what is deemed to be opinionated, but making a hard fast rule is often worst than not having a rule at all. The idea of making a mob of users or a select few moderators into a filtering algorithm by setting hard fast rules is silly since it defeats the purpose of having human input which is capable of handling delicate gray areas.

Comment: You've hit a touchy point of StackOverflow, ["discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).  StackOverflow is designed to cut straight to the answer, but opinion based questions evolve into either a back and forth or an infinite list.  "Best" questions are a prime example of this.  We by no means say they aren't good content, they are simply better served by another forum.

Comment: Further, if I can advise, starting by accusing someone of being "anti-intellectual" is unfair and doesn't generally create constructive discourse.

Comment: I wonder why this was made Community Wiki... ;)

Comment: @hichris123 downvote cowardice, I suppose.

Comment: @user148298 : I couldn't agree more. It's ironic you get downvoted for pointing out what IMO is the most serious problem at StackOverflow.